# Defining class methods in PHP

Tags: php, class

Is it possible in `PHP (as it is in C++)` to declare a `class method` OUTSIDE the `class definition?`

Comment: As far as I know what you are asking is not possible in C++. You might want to clarify.

Comment: In C++ you can define functions outside of the class and if the first parameter is of that class type, then you get what looks like an overload (i.e. an explicit "this"). The method is used for things such as the << operator of std::cout, for example. Unfortunately, PHP does not recognize a type when calling a function. The number of parameters is the only thing one can use to distinguish between PHP functions. The function itself can test for a parameter type and act differently upon it, but two functions with the same name and same number of parameters is something illegal in PHP.

Answer (score 9):

No, as of PHP 5.2. However, you may use `__call` magic method to forward call to arbitrary function or method.

```
class A {

    public function __call($method, $args) {
        if ($method == 'foo') {
            return call_user_func_array('bar', $args);
        }
    }

}

function bar($x) {
    echo $x;
}

$a = new A();
$a->foo('12345'); // will result in calling bar('12345')
```

In PHP 5.4 there is support for *traits*. Trait is an implementation of method(s) that cannot be instantiated as standalone object. Instead, trait can be used to extend class with contained implementation. Learn more on Traits [here](http://www.stefan-marr.de/artikel/rfc-traits-for-php.html).

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible to add a method to a PHP class after it is defined. You want to use [classkit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.classkit.php), which is an "experimental" extension. It appears that this extension isn't enabled by default however, so it depends on if you can compile a custom PHP binary or load PHP DLLs if on windows (for instance Dreamhost does allow custom PHP binaries, and they're pretty easy to setup).

```
<?php
class A { }
classkit_method_add('A', 'bar', '$message', 'echo $message;', 
    CLASSKIT_ACC_PUBLIC); 
$a = new A();
$a->bar('Hello world!');
```

Example from the PHP manual:

```
<?php
class Example {
    function foo() {
        echo "foo!\n";
    }
}

// create an Example object
$e = new Example();

// Add a new public method
classkit_method_add(
    'Example',
    'add',
    '$num1, $num2',
    'return $num1 + $num2;',
    CLASSKIT_ACC_PUBLIC
);

// add 12 + 4
echo $e->add(12, 4);
```

Comment: Note that this requires a PECL extension that everyone does not automatically have on their server. Also, it is now called runkit instead. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-add.php

Answer (score 3):

You could perhaps override [__call or __callStatic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) to locate a missing method at runtime, but you'd have to make up your own system for locating and calling the code. For example, you could load a "Delegate" class to handle the method call.

Here's an example - if you tried to call $foo->bar(), the class would attempt to create a FooDelegate_bar class, and call bar() on it with the same arguments. If you've got class auto-loading set up, the delegate can live in a separate file until required...

```
class Foo {

    public function __call($method, $args) {
        $delegate="FooDelegate_".$method;
        if (class_exists($delegate))
        {
             $handler=new $delegate($this);
             return call_user_func_array(array(&$handler, $method), $args);
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As PHP 5.3 supports closures, you can dynamically define instance methods as variables holding closures:

```
$class->foo = function (&$self, $n) {
  print "Current \$var: " . $self->var . "\n";
  $self->var += $n;
  print "New \$var:     " .$self->var . "\n";
};
```

Taking `$self` (you can't use `$this` outside object context) as a reference (`&`), you can modify the instance.

However, problems occur when you try to call the function normally:

```
$class->foo(2);
```

You get a fatal error. PHP thinks `foo` is a method of `$class`, because of the syntax. Also, you must pass the instance as the first argument.

There is luckily a special function for calling functions by name called `call_user_func`:

```
call_user_func($class->foo, &$class, 2);
# => Current $var: 0
# => New $var:     2
```

Just remember to put `&` before the instance variable.

What's even easier is if you use the `__call` magic method:

```
class MyClass {
  public function __call ($method, $arguments)  {
    if (isset($this->$method)) {
      call_user_func_array($this->$method, array_merge(array(&$this), $arguments));
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can call `$class->foo(2)` instead. The magic `__call` method catches the call to an unknown method, and calls the closure in the `$class->foo` variable with the same name as the called method.

Of course, if `$class->var` was private, the closure in stored in the `$class->foo` variable wouldn't be able to access it.

Comment: Note that the use of & when calling a function is not legal in PHP. It was accepted a while back (probably necessary in PHP 4) but today you get warnings or errors when you run that code `call_user_func($class->foo, &$class, 2);`.

Comment: I know. It was necessary before

Comment: And furthermore, in the latest PHP versions, you can use $this in closures.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can extend previously declared classes, though, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not posible. if you define function/method outside class construct it becomes global function.

Comment: All functions defined outside of a class are not global. If you save the function in a variable, then it is not global. (`$func = function() {...};`)

Answer (score 0):

C++ can't do this either. Did you mix up declaration with de*finition*?

Answer (score 0):

No, as everyone has said, it is not strictly possible.

However, you can do [something like this](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/17-Extending-Symfony) to emulate a mixin in PHP or add methods to a class at runtime, which is about as close as you're going to get. Basically, it's just using design patterns to achieve the same functionality. Zope 3 does something similar to emulate mixins in Python, another language that doesn't support them directly.

Comment: Your statement about Python is incorrect, since Python does support multiple inheritance, and indeed does support defining methods on runtime.