# Add method in an std object in php

Tags: php, object, stdclass

Is it possible to add a method/function in this way, like

```
$arr = array(
    "nid"=> 20,
    "title" => "Something",
    "value" => "Something else",
    "my_method" => function($arg){....}
);
```

or maybe like this

```
$node = (object) $arr;
$node->my_method=function($arg){...};
```

and if it's possible then how can I use that function/method?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot dynamically add a method to the stdClass and execute it in the normal fashion.  However, there are a few things you can do.

In your first example, you're creating a [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php).  You can execute that closure by issuing the command:

```
$arr['my_method']('Argument')
```

You can create a stdClass object and assign a closure to one of its properties, but due to a syntax conflict, you cannot directly execute it.  Instead, you would have to do something like:

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->method = function($arg) { ... }
$func = $node->method;
$func('Argument');
```

Attempting

```
$node->method('Argument')
```

would generate an error, because no method "method" exists on a stdClass.

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938004/how-to-add-a-new-method-to-a-php-object-on-the-fly) for some slick hackery using the magic method [__call](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call).

Comment: +1, It's done in other ways long ago, Someone edited the answer, see the date but thanks for your effort.

Comment: Whoops!  I completely overlooked that.  Thank you though.

Answer (score 37):

This is now possible to achieve in PHP 7.1 with anonymous classes

```
$node = new class {
    public $property;

    public function myMethod($arg) { 
        ...
    }
};

// and access them,
$node->property;
$node->myMethod('arg');
```

Comment: Nice one, I was mocking some data and this proved pretty helpful.

Comment: but does this add a new function to an already defined object?

Comment: @Geomorillo, No, it does not add to object, you can "add function to class" with `extends` on (anonymous) class. It is php, it is not JavaScript. But on other answers you can see also unreadable solutions with `__call`.

Answer (score 13):

Since PHP 7 it is also possible to directly invoke an anonymous function property:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->printMessage = function($message) { echo $message . "\n"; };
echo ($obj->printMessage)('Hello World'); // Hello World
```

Here the expression `$obj->printMessage` results in the anonymous function which is then directly executed with the argument `'Hello World'`. It is however necessary to put the function expression in paranetheses before invoking it so the following will still fail:

```
echo $obj->printMessage('Hello World'); 
// Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::printMessage()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to create an anonymous class and proxy the call via the magic function `__call`, with arrow functions you can even keep reference to context variables:

```
 new Class ((new ReflectionClass("MyClass"))->getProperty("myProperty")) {
            public function __construct(ReflectionProperty $ref)
            {
                $this->setAccessible = fn($o) => $ref->setAccessible($o);
                $this->isInitialized = fn($o) => $ref->isInitialized($o);
                $this->getValue = fn($o) => $ref->getValue($o);
            }

            public function __call($name, $arguments)
            {
                $fn = $this->$name;
                return $fn(...$arguments);
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class myclass {
function __call($method, $args) {
if (isset($this->$method)) {
$func = $this->$method;
return call_user_func_array($func, $args);
}
}
}
$obj = new myclass();
 $obj->method = function($var) { echo $var; };

$obj->method('a');
```

Or you can create defult class and use...