# Php - Dynamically added method is not callable

Tags: php, anonymous-function, dynamic-properties

I have some confusions! I've a simple class as given below

```
class MyClass {
    public $bar;
}
```

Then I made an instance

```
$cls = new MyClass;
```

Then I've assigned value to my public property `$bar` from outside of the class

```
$cls->bar='Bar';
```

Then I've added new public property `$baz` and assigned value to it from outside of the class

```
$cls->baz='Baz';
```

Then I've added a new public property `$showBar` and assigned value to it from outside of the class and this time the value is an anonymous function

```
$cls->showBar = function(){
    return $this->bar;
};
```

Then I've dumped the `$cls` using `var_dump($cls);` instance and output is

```
object(MyClass)[10]
  public 'bar' => string 'Bar' (length=3)
  public 'baz' => string 'Baz' (length=3)
  public 'showBar' => 
    object(Closure)[11]
```

Seems that all the public properties are available that I've added including the `anonymous` function and then I've done

```
echo $cls->bar; // Bar
echo $cls->baz; // Baz
echo $cls->showBar(); // error
```

The public property `showbar` is available in the class (the var_dump shows it) but when I call the function it says

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method MyClass::showBar() in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\phpTutorialInfo\bind\bindtoCls.php on line 234

**The question is :** It's possible to add new properties after initialization (works fine with a scalar value) and also the `showbar` seems available then why can't `Php` recognize it and If it's because it's value is a an anonymous function then why it's available in the `var_dump` output including the function itself and why `Php` let me assign the value (anonymous function), it should have thrown an error when I was trying to assign the value of `showbar` property ? Is that possible at all ?

Comment: I think the way you're calling the showBar() function, it might not think of $this as being the object $cls.  Did you get an actual error message?  Posting it may help illuminate things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lambda Functions in PHP aren't Logical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080248/lambda-functions-in-php-arent-logical)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot call the function this way. That's because PHP allows to have variables an functions having the same name in a class. If you use the function operator `()` PHP will only look into the list of functions and don't look at variables that are closures.

As of PHP5.4 a solution could look like this:

```
class MyClass {

    public function __call($fname, $args) {
        // bind the `this` scope to use
        $cl = $this->{$fname}->bindTo($this);
        // call the function and pass args to it
        return call_user_func_array($cl, $args);
    }

}
```

Example:

```
$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->func = function() {
    echo 'We are in ' . get_class($this);
};

$obj->func(); // We are in MyClass
```

You can test this [here](https://eval.in/36096)

Comment: `echo $cls->showBar->__invoke();` will not work as he's setting the closure and using `$this` when out of context, I believe the `__call` magic method may help.

Comment: `bind` and `bindTo` is PHP 5.4+ only, and closures are PHP 5.3+. (just an fyI)

Comment: yeah, I've seen this just a moment ago :)

Comment: result is `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in D:\xampp\htdocs\phpTutorialInfo\bind\bindtoCls.php on line 237`. I'm using `Php 5.4`.

Comment: This `$cls->func = function() { return $this->bar; };` won't work and I'm asking for this, is that possible at all ? Pleas heck my question, I've used `$this`.

Comment: @RobW Thx for helping me out with debugging this.. ;) ... However, now when it is ready I'm not sure anymore that binding the this scope without having control over it may not wanted in most situations.. What do you say?

Comment: Check out some of the comments on php.net: http://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php

Comment: I've checked it out already and this question is buzzing around my head since ages, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503212/add-method-in-an-std-object-in-php) of mine.

Comment: @hek2mgl, Thanks for your effort and nice answer.

Comment: @SheikhHeera You are welcome. It's an interesting problem +1. (I had almost the same today ;)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add a method dynamically in PHP. What you have done is adding a custom property, which is a function. But this does not makes it a method. To illustrate the difference, you can create a class, with a property & a method with the same name:

```
class A {
    public $test = 42;
    public test() { return 43; }
}

$a = new A;
$a->test === 42;
$a->test() === 43;
```

Comment: closures can be methods as a property, though.

Comment: No, closures can be bound to an object, but that doesn't makes them methods, i.e. you cannot call them like `$object->closureAsProperty()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `call_user_func`. Example:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    public $bar;
}
$cls = new MyClass;
$cls->bar='Bar';
$cls->baz='Baz';
$cls->showBar = function() use ($cls) {
    return $cls->bar;
};

echo call_user_func($cls->showBar); // Bar
?>
```

You may want to define the `__call` magic method so it may be possible to `return $this->bar` instead of passing `$cls` in the closure.

Comment: This will work (I've already tested it) but `$this` is not applicable inside closure. I'm just trying to simulate `JavaScript`'s `prototype` if it's possible at all, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: The thing with this solution is ... you're kind of just "reinventing the wheel" when you just want to access `$cls->bar` directly; though that's just for this example. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I'm just trying to add methods after an object's initialization using `Closure`.