# How to split a PHP class to separate files?

Tags: php, class

I want to do something like class categories in Objective-C, to define a class in one file, implement some core methods there, then implement some helper methods in another without subclassing or interfaces, just "continue" the class.

Possible in PHP?

Comment: Isn't a [require_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) enough?

Comment: I want to use the private stuff of the class in both places (like some shared private function, and some instance variables).

Comment: I thought something similar, in being able to 'extend' a method inside a class for client specific code, for multi client installations. Splitting into separate files is easy enough, especially with autoloader.

Comment: Could you make an example and explain why extending the class is not indicated?

Comment: Semantic stuff. A class managing the database is not really like a children of some class with helper methods only. Anyway, I will compose the tools via a simple instance then.

Comment: Alright I see now what you mean. Well, in some way, you could even consider ALL of your classes like children of a generic class which contains those helper methods. As you said, semantic stuff.

Comment: PHP is not objective-C, don't expect it to work the same way.  The only thing that might come remotely close in PHP is traits and as they're relatively new I wouldn't depend on PHP hosts having a PHP version that supports them available.

Comment: I tried traits just before, but I cannot refer to the same $this in that way. It is the same then like if I used some DBHelpers::dissectFields(); static stuff, or so.

Comment: Such things are quite ugly anyway, no matter what you call them (mixins, traits, whatever obj-c calls the thing you're describing.  Probably better to have helper classes that can be passed into the main class that provide plugin functionality.

Comment: @GordonM By the way, I borrowed some Obective-C-like stuff, for some complex classes I extract the public interface to a separate file (the same like header files), so it is less error-prone.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

a-priori PHP doest not give you this feature by language construction, the whole class *must* be in a single file.

Now there are tricks that could do the stuff, *but* they are quite heavy CPU demanding:

You can for example dissociate your classes between different files, then load the files and build a single string with the whole code, then do an eval(string) to interprete the classes and build them into the runnable code area.

not really a good idea btw for many reasons

Comment: I will go another way, there is many possible design, I just wanted to know if there is such a language feature.

Comment: Eval is not evil, the people using eval in unsafe or inefficient (eg, in a loop) ways are evil.

Comment: @ChinotoVokro exactly. eval can be used well for example for dynamically build condisions or stuff like this, but one has to be very careful with it, and either try to keep eval as far away from user input as possible or at least do some HEAVY sanitizing on the inputs.

Answer (score 51):

As of PHP 5.4, you can accomplish this with [Traits](http://php.net/trait). To quote the official documentation:

> Traits [enable] a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in several independent classes living in different class hierarchies. [...] A Trait is similar to a class, but only intended to group functionality in a fine-grained and consistent way. It is not possible to instantiate a Trait on its own. It is an addition to traditional inheritance and enables horizontal composition of behavior; that is, the application of class members without requiring inheritance.

Using a trait allows you to store helper methods that address cross-cutting concerns in a central place and use these methods in whatever classes you need.

```
// File "HelperMethodTrait.php"
trait HelperMethodTrait
{
    public function myIncredibleUsefulHelperFunction()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}

// File "MyClass.php"
class MyClass
{
    use HelperMethodTrait;

    public function myDomainSpecificFunction()
    {
        return "foobar";
    }
}

$instance = new MyClass();
$instance->myIncredibleUsefulHelperFunction(); // 42
```

Comment: I tried with traits, but they don't share one common scope. I could not access one's reference in another. Seems like a static function collection to me.

Answer (score 7):

If your only goal is to make the class definition file smaller, you can include files within a function definition

```
class MyClass {
    public function doStuff($foo,$bar) {
        global $quz;
        include('MyClass.doStuff.php');
    }
}
```

Within the include, your local scope applies ($foo,$bar and $quz will be defined)

I'm not sure what the overhead is - the include seems to happen at run-time, not compile time (since an include can actually return a value ..)

Comment: Does anyone know of any OSS project that does this? When you include files in your classes like this, how do you store and name your files?

Answer (score 4):

I think you better split your class in n parts along functional criteria, and then use the dependency injection pattern to "inject" class A into class B in the constructor for B, without a need for subclassing/interfaces.

Comment: I just ran across this thread by accident, because a friend of mine asked how he could divide a class, and after some consideration I also would say that "dependency injection" is the right way to do it here. It's not exactly what the author wants here, but as close a possible in PHP.

Comment: Can you add an example or a link here to explain your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this method to add functions to some objects externally, which is different from adding methods to the class itself.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2938020/2277620

Comment: Whoa, not bad, but the same with traits, these could be just static function out of object context.

Comment: No, not static. Normal functions. `$a = new test0();

$a->neu = function(){
    print( "neue funktion: " . $this->name . "\n");
};

$a->name = "testclass";

$a->neu();
`

Answer (score 1):

Another not-so-good-way is it create a multiple subclasses so every level of subclasses add only a 'group' of functions.

I used this trick in a single case where a class was more than 10k rows.

Now I've 6 levels of inheritance where every level add a single 'category' of functions the the "previous level" class.

Not so cpu-consuming, ugly to see, not so difficult to maintain

Answer (score 0):

**It is highly dependant on what you wish to achieve.** I had this bright idea doing what you wish to do. I likes the key words set, get run delete etc. Suppose there was a class and I wanted set of delete. As Ph.T pointed out class needs to be in single file

So make abc->set in one file and abc->get in another file made no use and sense.

So had to lot of rethinking and think of classes as micro services doing specific tasks broken down in functionality.

Solution went with name spacing.

```
        namespace A;
    class Get{public static function myCode(){}
public static function myAnotherCode(){}}
```

this would then be called A\Get::myCode(); or A\Get::myAnotherCode();
Similarly set would be

```
        namespace A;
    class Set{public static function myCode(){}
public static function myAnotherCode(){}}
```

This would then be called A\Set::myCode(); or A\Set::myAnotherCode();

Then user spl_autoload_register to load classes remember to replace \ with /

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
 require_once __DIR__ . '/' . strtolower(str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php')
});
```

and directory structure is as following

```
main (folder)
--  A (folder)
    --  set.php (file)
    --  get.php (file)
```

we asked for A\Get::myCode()
require would see it as A/Get.php then run its logic whether it is right name space or class etc.

good side of it if planned out right is it would force you to run things run in logical not just wishy washy there and there. Second you would only load functionality what you need not just whole bunch of this and that.

down side two parts of classes wont share between them unless one extends one from another which would defy the whole logic because other one would be loaded as a consequence any ways.

Careful negation has to be made as in what logic and planning data will be shared and has to be worked out before hand.

```
namespace A;
class Universal {
protected static $share_one;
protected static $share_two;
}

namespace A;
class Set extends Universal {
public static function myCode(){ parent::$share_one ='wow';}
}

namespace A;
class Get extends Universal {
public static function myCode(){ return parent::$share_one;}
    }

    main (folder)
    --  A (folder)
        --  universal.php (file)
        --  set.php (file)
        --  get.php (file)
```

run the code and see the magic

```
 A\Set::myCode();
 echo  A\Get::myCode();
```

if you only need one set of functionality e.g. get then just use get  `echo  A\Get::myCode();` would work without errors.

To be honest without playing around with name spaces its just expenditure of time earning headaches.
Side note: if done right it can speed up things as class universal wont load twice. even if called gazillion times whats what we want load defaults and then populate them where ever we need them. I have made huge classes where besides defaults only needed few functions rest was just memory load. breaking down just spead up things.