# Undefined method when using anonymous functions

Tags: php

PHP returns `Call to undefined method stdClass::fragmentr()` for the following code:

```
$core = new \StdClass;

$core->fragmentr = function($frag) {
    $path = sprintf("fragments/%s.php", $frag);

    if(is_file($path)) {
        include $path;
    } else {
        header("Location: ./?p=500");
        exit;
    }
}

/* SNIP */

$core->fragmentr('header');
```

However, the function $core->fragmentr is clearly defined as an anonymous function assigned to a variable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your stdClass doesn't have a method called: `fragmentr`, but it has a property called: `fragmentr` so you can do something like this:

```
$property = $core->fragmentr;
$property("header");
```

You can't call your [Closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) directly as you can see, so you have to assign it to a variable and then you can call it

Comment: Is there any way to call it using $var->func() syntax besides making a class? But thanks, this is a good answer.

Comment: @Saikyr Not directly, but you could do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2938020/3933332