# php dynamically append method to class

Tags: php

Need dynamically append method to class.

My code:

```
<?php

class stdClass1 {
    public function __call($method, $arguments) {
        return call_user_func_array(Closure::bind($this->$method, $this, get_called_class()), $arguments);
    }
}

class stdClass2 {

    function stdRunMethod() {
        $obj = new stdClass1();
        $obj->test = function() {
           echo 'a simple function';
        };
        $obj->test();

        $obj2 = new stdClass1();
        $obj2->test();
    }

}

$obj = new stdClass2();
$obj->stdRunMethod();
```

Question: why `test` method run only for first instance of `stdClass1` class? How to append this method for all new instances?

Comment: Because you only assign the function to the property of the first object. When you modify the object, you don't modify the class.

Comment: Yes. This way I can add methods to class instances. But I need dynamically add methods directly to the classes. Is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps using Reflection it is possible. Or maybe you can create a container to add the property after object creation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a new method to a php object on the fly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938004/how-to-add-a-new-method-to-a-php-object-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this instead ([demo](https://eval.in/626828)):

```
   <?php 

    class stdClass1 extends \stdClass
    {
        private static $addedClosures = array();

        public function __set($name, $value)
        {
            if ($value instanceof \Closure) {
                self::$addedClosures[$name] = $value;
            }
            else {
                parent::__set($name, $value);
            }
        }

        public function __call($method, $arguments)
        {
            if (isset(self::$addedClosures[$method]))
                return call_user_func_array(self::$addedClosures[$method], $arguments);
            return call_user_func_array($method, $arguments);
        }
    }

    class stdClass2 extends \stdClass
    {

        function stdRunMethod()
        {
            $obj = new stdClass1();
            $obj->test = function () {
                print_r('a simple function');
            };
            $obj->test();

            $obj2 = new stdClass1();
            $obj2->test();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it only runs once is that each copy of `stdClass1` maintains their own set of variables. In the following

```
$obj1 = new stdClass1();
$obj1->a = '1';

$obj2 = new stdClass1();
$obj2->a = '2';

echo $obj1->a;
```

You'll get the value `1` as the output. Because in most cases they maintain different references. Unless you use the `static` keyword. Static properties are shared between all instances of the class, and should be used carefully, but that's what you're thinking of. What you're thinking of can be done like this

```
<?php

class stdClass1 {
    private static $methods = [];

    public function __call($method, $arguments) {
        return call_user_func_array(Closure::bind($this->methods[$method], $this, get_called_class()), $arguments);
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        if (is_callable($value)) {
            $this->methods[$name] = $value;
        } else {
            parent::__set($name, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

Here we're using a static, defined property to hold all of the dynamic methods, and we're using the magic `__set` property to set the methods in to the array.

That being said, dynamically loading methods in to an object is bad. Don't do that

Comment: Why you use $this-> to call static array?

Comment: Just used to it. Feel free to use `self::` instead

Comment: seems to give nearly the same errors as the original question. The selected answer works.